# HP ALM 12.20 not opening attachments

Tags: quality-center, hp-alm, hp-alm-12.20

We have just moved from HP ALM version 11.52 to 12.20, but in new version we have encountered a problem: all attachments won't open (we use IE10, IE11).

1. User double clicks on attachment link.
2. Progress bar is displayed for short time.
3. Progress bar disappears and nothing happens after that.

Previously: image was opened in new window. (I've checked `Downloads` folder and have not found anything of this kind)

You can see "Edit step window":

[image]

Does anyone know how to handle this problem?

Comment: We (me and my team) too faced this issue with HP ALM (not sure about the version number), but the only solution we got was to upload the image again. As we had to use HP ALM for only 2-3 months, so we didn't bothered much about this issue.

Comment: @Dhiman, thanks for reply! This will not work for us as we have thousands of requirements, thousands of defects and thousands of tests

Comment: It took us more than 3 months to configure all the projects. I assume the configuration will be wipe out if you re-install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have made rollback and reinstall HP ALM 12.20 on the server and on local machines, this helped to solve the problem.